# Recursion and Loops - Maximum Call Stack Exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to build a function that adds up all the numbers within a string... for example, 'dlsjf3diw62' would end up being 65.

I tried to be clever and put together a recursive function:

```
function NumberAddition(str) { 
  var numbers='1234567890';
  var check=[];
  str=str.split[''];
  function recursive(str,check) {
    if (str.length==0)
      return check;
    else if (numbers.indexOf(str[0])>=0)
    {
      for (i=0;i<str.length;i++){
        if (numbers.indexOf(str[i])<0)
          check.push(str.slice(0,i));
        str=str.slice(i);
        return recursive(str,check);
      }
    }
    else
      str.shift();
    return recursive(str,check);
  }
```

You'll see that I'm trying to get my numbers returned as an array in the array named check.  Unfortunately, I have a maximum call stack size exceeded, and I'm not sure why!  The recursion does have a base case!!  It ends once str no longer has any contents.  Why wouldn't this work?  Is there something I'm missing?

-Will

Comment: Learn to use your browser's developer tools and step through your code. Also, there would be a far easier way of achieving what you're trying.

Comment: The code you posted seems to be missing something; it's hard to tell where the function ends, and in particular something looks wrong with the last few lines. There's a missing curly brace.

Comment: What is the far easier way?

Comment: @user3546595 strip out the numeric substrings with a regular expression and then reduce the result.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy and paste to the last line.  It's really the function named'Recursive' that isn't working.

Comment: There are some jobs that lend themselves to recursion. I don't really see this being one of them unless it's purely for self-learning.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same thing with a far easier solution, using regular expressions, as follows:

```
var str = 'dlsjf3diw62';
var check = str.match(/\d+/g); // this pattern matches all instances of 1 or more digits
```

Then, to sum the numbers, you can do this:

```
var checkSum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
    checkSum += parseInt(check[i]);
}
```

Or, slightly more compact:

```
var checkSum = check.reduce(function(sum, num){ return sum + parseInt(num) }, 0);
```

Comment: Where's the addition?

Comment: Well, their code only produced the array, so thought I'd match it.

Comment: I think you want `/\d+/g`

Comment: You're missing the `+` in `/\d+/g`, be cause the OP said the output for `dlsjf3diw62` should be 65 not 11.

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand how they got 65 to be honest!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your recursion doesn't work is the case where you do enter the `for` loop, because you've found a digit, but the digits continue to the end of the string. If that happens, the `return` inside the `for` loop never happens, and the loop ends. After that, the `.shift()` does **not** happen, because it's in that `else` branch, so you return re-process the same string.

You shouldn't solve this particular problem that way, but the code makes a good example of the anti-pattern of having `return` statements inside `if` bodies followed by `else`. Your code would be clearer (and would work) if it looked like this:

```
function recursive(str, check) {
    if (str.length == 0)
        return check;

    if (numbers.indexOf(str[0]) >= 0) {
        // Find the end of the string of digits, or
        // the end of the whole thing
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length && numbers.indexOf(str[i]) >= 0; i++);

        check.push(str.slice(0, i));
        str = str.slice(i);
        return recursive(str, check);
    }

    // A non-digit character
    str.shift();
    return recursive(str, check);
}
```

In that version, there are no `else` clauses, because the two `if` clauses *always* involve a `return`.  The `for` loop is changed to simply *find* the right value of "i" for the subsequent slicing.

*edit* — one thing this doesn't fix is the fact that you're pushing *arrays* into your "check" list. That is, the substring "62" would be pushed as the array `["6", "2"]`. That's not a huge problem; it's solved with the addition of a `.join()` in the right place.